# Sorry, the command is not available in this version

Tags: vimrc, macvim, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-vim-plug

I am trying to install the `UltiSnips` plugin using `vim-plug` (for everything else, vim-plug works just fine). I put this:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
    Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
call plug#end()
```

It will save and I can successfully perform `:PlugInstall` and even edit text in MacVim. But when I go back into the `.vimrc` and trying to insert anything, I get the following error:

```
(This is all that is in the `.vimrc`)

Error detected while processing TextChangedI Autocommands for "*"..script /Users
/grpgrok/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim:
line    7:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py3 import vim
```

Running `:py3 import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)`, I get `7fffffffffffffff True`, showing python3 both works and is 64-bit.

Edit:
I just ran `:echo has("python")` and `:echo has("python3")` and got 1 and 0 respectively. So apparently, I do have python but not python 3.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! That's odd... Does `:py3 import vim` work? (Wondering about the Python module named "vim", though I haven't seen that fail if `:py3` is available.) When you use `:version`, do you see `+python3` or `+python3/dyn` there? (Perhaps include output of `:version` and/or `vim --version` in your question.) Is it possible you have two versions of Vim installed and they have different settings such as Python support in only one of them?

Comment: @filbranden `+python3/dyn` is there (along with `+python/dyn`). When I try `:py3 import vim`, it just sends the cursor back to the top like any other `:py3 import [package]`. I have deleted and re-downloaded Vim and MacVim a few times but, as far as I can tell, there is only one version of Vim installed currently.

Comment: One more possibility, when you have both `+python/dyn` (for Python 2) and `+python3/dyn` for Python 3, then the first command that you execute (`:py` vs `:py3`) will determine which version of Python is available, and the other version is not... Is it maybe possible that something is loading Python 2 first and that's breaking Python 3 that's required by UltiSnips?

Comment: @filbranden I see how something could be calling Python 2 before Python 3. This is literally the first thing in `vimrc` and even if I put something like `:py3 1+1` on the very first line, I get `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: :py3 1+1 `

Comment: Sorry, I DON'T see how something could be calling py2 before py3

Comment: Does adding `let g:UltiSnipsUsePythonVersion = 3` to your `.vimrc` solve the issue? (If not, how about setting it to `2` instead?)